# ¿Por qué scanf se salta o no funciona?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

Buen día programadores.

Soy nuevo y estoy intentando crear un programa que me pregunte por dos números enteros tipo `unsigned char` para poder aplicar operaciones lógicas. Mi problema surge cuando corro el programa pero no me pregunta por el segundo número.
¿Alquién sabe por qué?

```
#include <stdio.h>        
    void pp(unsigned char z){
    printf("%3d (%02x)\n", z, z);
    }
int main() {
unsigned char entero1;
unsigned char entero2;
unsigned char z;

printf("Introducir un numero entero entre 0 y 255\n");
scanf("%c", &entero1);

printf("Introducir otro numero entero entre 0 y 255\n");
scanf("%c", &entero2);  

z=entero1 & entero2; pp(z);
z=entero1 | entero2; pp(z);
z=entero1 ^ entero2; pp(z);
z=z ^ entero2;   pp(z);
z=~z;        pp(z);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: El problema más probable es que tu segundo scanf te lea lo que quedó en el buffer de tu primera lectura. Puede que se rellene con otra cifra o con el INTRO de la primera lectura. Depura con watches en los entero1 y entero2 para confirmar.
La solución más sencilla es hacer flush del buffer tras cada lectura, con esto te aseguras que dejas el buffer vacío para siguientes lecturas.
Saludos.

Comment: Otro detalle... `fflush` **no se debe usar** con dispositivos de entrada, su uso se debe limitar a dispositivos de salida.

Comment: Yo siempre tuve problemas asi pero pude solucionarlo escribiendo la siguiente linea despues del scanf
fflush(stdin); http://www.carlospes.com/curso_de_lenguaje_c/01_11_la_funcion_fflush.php

Comment: Genial, vamos a hacer cosas que pueden (o no) funcionar. `fflush` solo se debería usar con buffers de salida, **nunca** de entrada. La razón es que no se garantiza el resultado esperado. [referencia](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/): *"In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior)."*

Comment: Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214828/7123) es relevante (aunque en ella se hacía una lectura de cadena antes del char, la explicación de "por qué se salta" es la misma.

Answer (score 4):

`%c` se usa para escanear caracteres, no números.

Si bien los caracteres se codifican con números, no es lo mismo leer un caracter a leer un número:

- Si el usuario escribe `1` tu recibes `'1'`, es decir, el caracter 1, que en codificación numérica ASCII sería 0x31 (en hexadecimal)
- Si el usuario escribe `a` tu recibes `'a'` o, en formato numérico 0x61.
- Nota que para leer un número de dos cifras con `%c` es necesario hacer dos lecturas (una primera para las decenas y una segunda para las unidades).

Para leer números has de configurar `scanf` para que interprete la entrada como numérica y para ello puedes usar `%d`:

```
printf("Introducir un numero entero entre 0 y 255\n");
scanf("%d", &entero1);
//     ^^ 

printf("Introducir otro numero entero entre 0 y 255\n");
scanf("%d", &entero2);
//     ^^
```

Y ahora la pregunta del millón ¿Por qué no *funciona* la segunda lectura?

La segunda lectura sí que estaba funcionando... pero no lee lo que tu esperas. Como habías configurado la entrada para leer caracteres, el sistema va a interpretar los saltos de línea como caracteres:

- Si tu introduces `1[ENTER] , la aplicación lee el caracter`'1'`en`entero1` y el salto de línea en el segundo.
- Si tu introduces `12[ENTER]`, la aplicación lee el caracter `'1'` en `entero1` y el caracter `'2'` en `entero2`.

Answer (score 2):

Es un problema bastante habitual. El problema ocurre porque cuando tú introduces el carácter en el primer scanf, luego pulsas la tecla Enter, que también es un carácter (un carácter especial, en realidad) y este te lo captura en el segundo scanf, por eso tienes esa sensación de que el segundo scanf no se está ejecutando.

Cuando haces un scanf de un número (%d) esto no ocurre ya que en ese caso se evitan automáticamente espacios en blanco y caracteres especiales (como el Enter), pero con un scanf de caracteres esto no ocurre. Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un espacio en blanco en el segundo scanf.

En lugar de poner

```
scanf("%c", &entero2);
```

pon

```
scanf(" %c", &entero2);
```

Así debería solucionarse tu problema. Siempre que tengas scanf de caracteres consecutivos, salvo el primero, procura ponerlos así.

Espero que esto solucione tu problema.

P.D.: No me había fijado pero como comentan en otra respuesta, otro problema es que estás intentando leer números con el %c en lugar del %d y eso no va a funcionar como tú esperas.