# Duda escanear caracter C

Tags: c, scanf

estoy empezando con C y aunque sé que debo hacerlo, no entiendo por qué debo poner un salto de línea antes de escanear el caracter.

scanf("**\n**%c", &c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Cadena: "); scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Char: "); scanf("\n%c", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando a `scanf()` le pasas la cadena de formato `"%s"` leerá todos los caracteres que encuentre en la entrada hasta el primer "espacio", considerando como tal el ASCII 32 (caracter de espacio), el ASCII 9 (tabulador) o el ASCII 10 o 13 (retorno de carro y nueva línea). Cuando encuentra uno de estos "blancos", no los lee. En la variable `str` tendrás todos los caracteres que ha leido hasta ese blanco.

El problema es que el blanco que no ha leído, queda ahí, en el buffer de entrada, esperando. La siguiente rutina que haga uso de la entrada estándar se encontrará con ese blanco como primer carácter. Normalmente, si el siguiente `scanf()` usa como cadena de formato `"%d"` o `"%f"`, o `"%s"`, esto no plantea problemas, pues esas cadenas de formato ignorarn todos los "blancos" hasta encontrar el primer carácter no-blanco y ahí comienzan su lectura.

Pero cuando tienes un `"%c"` aparecen los problemas, ya que esta cadena de formato significa simplemente "leer un carácter", el que sea, tanto si es blanco como si no. Por tanto `scanf()` encontraría el blanco que había quedado sin leer del `scanf()` anterior, y ese sería el carácter que leería.

Es habitual que el usuario, tras teclear su entrada en tu primer `scanf()` pulse retorno de carro. Ya que el retorno de carro es considerado "blanco", no formaría parte de la cadena leída en `str`, sino que quedaría en el buffer como he explicado, y el siguiente `scanf("%c", &c)` lo encontraría y te dejaría en `c` ese retorno de carro (ASCII 13).

Para evitarlo hay varias técnicas. Una de ellas es la que has usado de indicar a `scanf()` que antes del carácter que te interesa viene un retorno de carro, poniendo `"\n%c"` como cadena de formato.

Otra técnica habitual es hacer un `getch()`  tras el primer `scanf()` para así "consumir" el blanco que había quedado sin leer, tanto si es un retorno de carro como si es otro tipo de blanco.