# scanf(" %f") se saltea luego de scanf("%c")

Tags: c, scanf

El problema es simple, necesito insertar dos variables: nombre y altura. Sin embargo, cuando ingreso el nombre el programa se saltea el segundo scanf (el de altura).

```
char nombre[30];
int i;
float h;

printf("Enter names and surnames: ");
scanf("%c", &nombre);
printf("\nEnter height in meters: ");
scanf(" %f", &h);

gets(nombre);
printf("\nYour height is %f, and your initials are %c", h, nombre[0]);
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(nombre); i++)
{
    if(nombre[i] == ' ')
    {
        printf(", %c", nombre[i+1]);
    }
}

return 0;
```

El problema no ocurre cuando utilizo "%s" en vez de "%c", pero intento leer caracteres individualmente así que no sé si es una opción.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta a españo de lo contrario podrá terminar cerradal. Hi, welcome to stackoverflow in spanish, please, translate your question to spanish otherwise it could be closed.

Comment: disculpe, pensé que estaba en la página en inglés, sinceramente no estaba enterado de que había una alternativa en español

Comment: No te preocupes. Cuando indicas que el problema no sucede cuando lees con `scanf` la entrada reemplazando `%s` es porque `%s` denota un string que es lo que necesitas. En cambio con `%c` esperas un caracter y solamente uno, por lo que no lee toda la entrada que realmente necesitas.

Comment: fijate la explicación en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/214828/81450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analicemos paso a paso el programa.

Cuando se ejecute esta línea:

```c
printf("Enter names and surnames: ");
scanf("%c", &nombre);
```

El usuario solo puede ingresar un caracter. Por ejemplo, la letra `A` y este caracter se guardaría en la primera posición del array `nombre` (es decir, en `nombre[0]`).

Esto quiere decir, que si solo ingresas un caracter, el búfer del teclado quedaría con un salto de línea, esto no afectará al próximo `scanf`, ya que ignorará el salto de línea.

Si el usuario ingresara como altura: `12.3`. El búfer sigue quedando con el `\n`.

```c
printf("\nEnter height in meters: ");
scanf(" %f", &h);
```

Esto ocasiona que la función `gets` nunca se detenga para la espera de una cadena y esto se debe a que esta rutina deja de leer hasta encontrar un salto de línea.

```c
gets(nombre);
```

Después se imprime los datos que ingresó el usuario:

```c
printf("\nYour height is %f, and your initials are %c", h, nombre[0]);
```

Dándome como resultado:

```c
Your height is 12.3, and your initials are
```

Por supuesto, no se está imprimiendo el contenido de la primera posición del array `nombre` y esto se debe que la función `gets` como no pudo leer nada, asignó el caracter nulo en `nombre[0]` y dicho caracter no se lo puede imprimir con `%c` (sino con `%d`).

Hasta ahí, podríamos comprender como podría funcionar tu código ingresando esos datos.

Veamos otro caso. Si en la primera llamada de `scanf` ingreso un `Ramirez`, solo tomará el primer caracter de la cadena (la letra `R`), el resto se quedará en el búfer: `amirez`.

```
scanf("%c", &nombre);
```

El próximo `scanf` pide un flotante y solo ignora saltos de líneas pero como en el búfer quedó con mas caracteres, esto provoca que la lectura falle y esa es la razón del porque se salta la opción.

> > El problema no ocurre cuando utilizo "%s" en vez de "%c", pero intento leer caracteres individualmente así que no sé si es una opción.

Si haces algo como esto:

```c
printf("Enter names and surnames: ");
scanf("%s", &nombre);
```

La función `scanf` leerá los caracteres del búfer hasta encontrar un espacio o salto de línea. Esto es peligroso, aquí puedes desbordar el array `nombre` y esto provoca que `scanf` escriba en alguna dirección de memoria que no le corresponda al programa. En este hilo puedes encontrar mas información sobre eso: [¿Cómo evitar un desbordamiento de búfer cuando se pide una cadena con scanf?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf)
. De igual manera, en tu caso deberías de utilizar una función que si te permita leer cadenas con espacios.

Pero no, **no debes usar la función** `gets`. Es peligroso, también puedes desbordar el búfer. Para mas información, leer este hilo: [Es recomendable usar la función gets?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/427860/105299).

La función que conozco para leer cadenas con espacios y que sea seguro, es la función [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Su uso es sencillo:

```c
printf("Enter names and surnames: ");
fgets(nombre, sizeof nombre, stdin);
printf("\nEnter height in meters: ");
scanf("%f", &h);
```

De esta manera haces una lectura de forma segura. Un detalle importante es que la función `fgets` agregaría el salto de línea en el array. Eso se lo podría eliminar de esta forma:

```c
nombre[strlen(nombre) - 1] = '\0';
```

Y eso es todo..

El último código no tengo ni idea del porque lo usaste. Si quieres imprimir la cadena, simplemente usa:

```c
printf("name and surname: %s", nombre);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ahora el código funciona perfectamente :D (aunque creo que debo aclarar que el último fragmento es para sacar las iniciales de los nombres, así que no puedo reemplazarlo)